# Arbelos and circles of Archimedes proof using an inversion circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

In the image above, let $d$ denote the diameter of circle $\omega_4$, and set $d_1=AB$ and $d_2=BC$.  Assume everything that looks tangent is in fact tangent.

**Prove:**
$$\displaystyle d=\frac{d_1d_2}{d_1+d_2}$$

I'm supposed to use a circle of inversion centered at $A$, and orthogonal to $\odot\omega_4$ in my proof.  However, I would welcome any proof at all, even an elementary one.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's is another proof not using inversion, but elementary geometry: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4349197/947379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $r$ denote radii. The following equation can be established by applying the Pythagorean theorem to the right triangles XYD and XZD,

$$XD^2 = (r_1+r_4)^2 - (r_1-r_4)^2 = (r_3-r_4)^2-(2r_1-r_3-r_4)^2$$

which simplifies to 
$$r_3r_4=r_1(r_3-r_1)$$

Recognize $r_3=r_1+r_2$  to obtain

$$r_4=\frac{r_1r_2}{r_1+r_2}$$

which is equivalent to $\displaystyle d=\frac{d_1d_2}{d_1+d_2}$.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty cool.  But I have one sticky point of skepticism.  How do we know that Z lies to the left of D?

Comment: @BenW - Turns out it does not matter. If Z is on the right. The Pythagorean equation would be the same due to all the squared terms. You'd get the same result.

Comment: Cool, I kinda suspected that actually. Sorry I shoulda checked first to save you time. Thank you! Now, I need to figure out what software to use to draw this...

Comment: @BenW - no prob. you're welcome