# prove that two line segments are congruent (have the same length)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

**Problem.** In the diagram above, prove that $DE=DN$.

The reason I'm asking is because this is the main ingredient to answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513683/use-an-inversion-circle-to-prove-an-identity-for-the-arbelos-and-magic-twin-circ?noredirect=1#comment7226346_3513683).

It seems like it should be a simple high school geometry problem, but I can't seem to crack it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If all you are given is the two right angles and $GL=GN$, then it is not true. [If we made GL small, then $DN$ would be approx $DL$]

Answer (score 2):

Notice that when $GN=GL=x$ tends to a really small value, $DN$ and $DE$ will become part of a right angle triangle $\Delta DNE/\Delta DLE$. As the length of the hypotenuse and a side cannot be the same, the condition is false.

Comment: Okay, I agree.  I see that I need another ingredient from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513683/use-an-inversion-circle-to-prove-an-identity-for-the-arbelos-and-magic-twin-circ to make it work